# Selecting, Deleting jQuery based on wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard

What I would like is if there is NOT a word "link" in the href "www.1link.com" all the top classes 1-6 is changed to classdefault.

Also a different code that does the same thing except of adding "defaultclass" it removes all the classes 1-6 empty.

This is what I've tried so far and it hasn't worked

http://jsfiddle.net/yLxXn/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

if ($('a[href$="link"]')) {  
    // do something here  

$("[class^=content]").attr("class", "classdefault");

} 


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
if ($('a').attr('href').indexOf('link') != -1) {
// other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

If you want this to happen if it does not contain "link", change `>=` to `<=`. As following:

For replacing all classes:

```
$('div').find('a').each(function(){
    var hrefString = $(this).attr('href'); 
    if (hrefString.indexOf("link") <= 0){
        $('[class^=class]').attr('class', 'classdefault');
    }
});
```

For removing all classes:

```
$('div').find('a').each(function(){
    var hrefString = $(this).attr('href'); 
    if (hrefString.indexOf("link") <= 0){
        $('[class^=class]').removeClass();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi I was looking for the opposite, if it does not contain "link" then remove class or change class.

Comment: @DavidSmith to get the opposite, change `>=` to `<=` See my updated answer.